# Querying nested relations many to many with TypeORM

Tags: typeorm

I have three tables, `products`, `items`, and `parts`. The relation between them is `ManyToMany`, but at Typeorm level, I decided to use `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` because I want to use the intermediate table as an entity.

products

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { Item } from 'src/items/item.entity';


@Entity({ name: 'products' })
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 100 })
  code: string;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  description: string;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  filename: string;

  @Column({ default: false, nullable: false, name: 'is_deleted' })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', name: 'creation_date' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', name: 'last_modification_date' })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @OneToMany(() => Item, item => item.id)
  items: Item[];
}
```

items

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, JoinColumn, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { Part } from 'src/parts/part.entity';
import { Product } from 'src/products/product.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'items' })
export class Item {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Part, part => part.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "part_id", referencedColumnName: "id"})
  part: Part;

  @ManyToOne(() => Product, product => product.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "product_id", referencedColumnName: "id"})
  product: Product;

  @Column()
  quantity: number;

  @Column({ default: false, nullable: false, name: 'is_deleted' })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', name: 'creation_date' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', name: 'last_modification_date' })
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

parts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, ManyToOne, JoinColumn, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { Subvehicle } from "src/subvehicles/subvehicle.entity";
import { Item } from "src/items/item.entity";

@Entity({ name: 'parts'})
export class Part {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 255 })
  oem: string;

  @Column({ default: false, nullable: false, name: 'is_deleted' })
  isDeleted: boolean;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', name: 'creation_date' })
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp', nullable: false, default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', name: 'last_modification_date' })
  updatedAt: Date;
  
  @OneToMany(() => Item, item => item.id)
  items: Item[];
}
```

The issue is when I try to find the nested entities from the product

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Product) private productRepository: Repository<Product>) { }

  findAll(): Promise<Product[]> {
    return this.productRepository.find({ relations: ["items"] });
  }
}
```

I have been trying to fit this, but not sure why I am getting the error

> [Nest] 43784  - 09/21/2023, 10:58:25 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler]
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns') TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns')

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, I post the answer in case is useful to someone else

products

```
....
@OneToMany(() => Item, item => item.product)
items: Item[];
...
```

items

```
...
@ManyToOne(() => Part, part => part.id)
@JoinColumn({ name: "part_id", referencedColumnName: "id"})
part: Part;

@ManyToOne(() => Product, product => product.id)
@JoinColumn({ name: "product_id", referencedColumnName: "id"})
product: Product;
...
```

parts no need to specify the relationship

Then in the products service

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Product) private productRepository: Repository<Product>) { }

  findAll(): Promise<Product[]> {
    return this.productRepository.find({
      relations: {
        items: {
          part: {}
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```